# Query Results as Views on Local Host

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have Read Only access to Oracle Server. Sometimes, I write very lengthy Queries. Is there a way that I can save these Queries on Local Host as Views.

Example:

Remote Server : ABC  (I have read only Access)
Local Host: Localhost ( I am the Admin)

I built a query `select * from employee;` on Remote Server, and I want to save this query on my Localhost as View.

Is it possible? If yes, please advise, how do i achieve this.

Btw, I am using SQL Navigator to pull the data from the Server.

Comment: Why don't you just open Notepad, paste, then save?

Comment: You can create Database Links on Oracle similar to Linked Servers on SQL Server. Then you can create your own view on your local system which queries remote database objects over database links. Please refer to official documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm